# issue in datatable filter using custom ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am trying to filter *Datatable* using custom *Ajax call* through dopdown.
I am able to filter my required data. When I click on the dropdown I can get my filtered data, but when I click again and again on dopdown to test my code it give me error of:

> "TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"

I have tried to use datatable and jquery with asp.net mvc

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myTable").DataTable();

    });

        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Brands").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/PO/GetByBrand?brandName=' + $("#Brands").find("option:selected").text(),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tableDiv").empty();
                    $("#tableDiv").html(data);
                    // $("#ropdownDiv").html(data);

                },

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                },

            });

        });
```

I want to filter data as many times as I want but I could not filter it more than 4 or 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using some DataTables script I usually use the following cdn which works very well at the beginning of the scope.

```
<link href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" />
```

This can happen with script initialization at the same definition time. Define the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myTable").DataTable();

    });
```

after initializing your html with this id and joining with the codes below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Brands").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/PO/GetByBrand?brandName=' + $("#Brands").find("option:selected").text(),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tableDiv").empty();
                    $("#tableDiv").html(data);
                    // $("#ropdownDiv").html(data);

                },

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                },

            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how `$("#myTable")` and `$("#tableDiv")` are related.

As on `$("#Brands")` change you are reloading `$("#tableDiv")` content only.

For this error

> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a functio

Check if somehow jquery or datatable js is getting reset. Good guess would be on html reset or window reload. Ideally jquery should load before Datatable script.